# Least Squares Conformal Map Algorithm for UV coordinates

Tags: algorithms, 3d

Can someone explain Least Squares Conformal Map in terms using Vertices(Vx,Vy,Vz) and  UV coordinates or ST coordinate? I have read the lscm paper but I need it in XYZ value to understand it.
http://alice.loria.fr/publications/papers/2002/lscm/lscm.pdf

For example,

Like planar, those are very simple projection algorithms that give you a UV value directly from a XYZ value, without taking into account the connectivity with other vertices.

•For cylindrical: convert (x, y, z) into Cylindrical Coordinates (ρ, φ, z), and use as UV coordinates u = φ and v = z

•For spherical: convert (x, y, z) in Spherical Coordinates (r, θ, φ), and use as UV coordinates u = θ and v = φ

Spherical, Cubic, and Parabolic Environment Mappings http://www.unc.edu/~zimmons/cs238/maps/environment.html

Comment: Did you get the answer somewhere else? I am also looking for this.